# CSS infinite animation stops moving when the component is toggled

Tags: css, ios, animation, ios13, keyframe

#### Reproduction link

https://codesandbox.io/s/infinite-animation-bug-vanilla-xi5uh?file=/src/index.js

#### Code

```
root/                             
  ├── src/
  │   ├── styles.css
  │   └── index.js
  └─╴index.html
```

**styles.css**
from https://loading.io/css/

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="lds-dual-ring" id="loading"></div>
    <button id="toggle">toggle</button>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```js
let isLoading = true;
const $toggleButton = document.getElementById("toggle");
const $loadingIndicator = document.getElementById("loading");


$toggleButton.addEventListener("click", (event)=>{
  if(isLoading){
    $loadingIndicator.style.display = "none";
    isLoading=false
    return;
  }
  $loadingIndicator.style.display = "";
  isLoading = true
})
```

#### What is expected?

CSS animation works normally.

#### What is actually happening?

CSS animation stops running when toggled.

---

- env: Iphone IOS13 * It only happens in **IOS13**
- reproduction video
  [image: IOS13]

Comment: I am not seeing this issue on your link in either chrome nor safari on mac, the animation resumes as expected. Or on my iphone on iOS14. It could be an iOS 13 issue, but that won't be resolved anymore.

Comment: Sounds like an iOS simulator issue.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Seems it's an IOS 13 issue.
@jeremykenedy Added my Code. Thanks

Comment: I've tested with pure javascript and found out same issue happens. It was IOS13 issue not the vue issue.